# symfony 2.8 google drive api V2

Tags: php, api, symfony, google-drive-realtime-api

I have a problem using google drive api v2 on symfony 2.8
I want to get all videos from my drive directory,
I have more than 200 video, but when I call listFiles I only get 100! why ?
this is the code I use to get the files:

```
                $file_list = $drive_service->files->listFiles(array('q'=>"mimeType CONTAINS 'video/' and '$folderId' in parents"))->getItems();
```

and when I execute this :

```
$drive_service->files->listFiles()->count();
```

I also get response 100

please help,I want to get all the files or at least 1000.

Comment: Is there a second argument "maxResult" . Because the official API got it.

Comment: @AlexandrePainchaud yes, I added maxResult, at first it didn't work, but for some reasons when I added another fields it worked, so problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I added maxResult, at first it didn't work, but for some reasons when I added another fields it worked, so problem is solved.